# Books or guides regarding secure key storage and database encryption

Tags: database, security, encryption, keys

I have an idea for a SaaS product I want to create, however, this product will store extremely sensitive data that needs to be encrypted at rest. The trouble is not so much the encryption, but the problem of securely storing the keys so that in the event the server was somehow compromised, the keys couldn't just be recovered and used to decrypt the database.

Are there any decent books to guides regarding database encryption, and in particular secure key storage? This seems to be a less than straightforward topic and something that is difficult to get right. I'm seeing multiple ways to attack such a system, but unable to come up with one that is secure enough to store highly confidential information.

Comment: What database are you using?  Oracle, for example, has native support for encrypting data at rest as part of Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) where it can store the decryption key in the server's Hardware Security Module (HSM) which takes care of secure storage for you.  Potentially, you could also deploy servers that have self-encrypting hard drives though that may get rather expensive if you scale up.  If you need to implement the functionality yourself, that's obviously much more difficult.

Comment: @JustinCave Preferably Postgresql or MySQL in a pinch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bible is Applied Cryptography by Bruce Schneier, however, I suggest starting with "Secrets and Lies" and "Beyond Fear".